# Improving scalability of .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asp.net-web-api, scalability

I have a .net application which is having multiple technologies used and components i.e. WCF, C#, Web API. Application scales well till a certain level, but after that it starts to break pretty quick and badly.

quick example: after 250 users connecting to the system it crashes and cannot handle any further connections/users.

Can someone please suggest pointers to improve scalability in general terms i need to follow in the above mentioned technologies, or IIS.

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can start to profile your system unsing **PerfMon** or **XPerf** and check the cause of your crashes. It could be the RAM usage. Having multiple active sessions could lead to insufficient memory.

Also maybe the CPU cannot serve such a high number of symultaneous requests or you just don't have the network bandwidth.

Once you find the crash cause, you can start optimizing your code (e.g. reducing memory footprint, optimize long duration functions, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches here and you will probably need to look at both.

First is the time taken to process requests on WebAPI and WCF. Use tools like RedGate Performance Profiler or other similar ones to determine what is taking the most time per request.

Then look to either

- Refactor the code
- Use caching where possible

The next is then looking at your hardware. If you take Azure for example, choosing a larger instance and more of them, in which Azure will provide the load balancing. If you don't use Azure it may be a little harder for you to setup load balancing but that is the only other way to scale.

Check your code first with performance tools, then look to hardware if it can't go any faster. But 250 users shouldn't be too much of an issue hence I think your code could be enhanced performance wise.